# The LaTeX gives error for the figure codes

Tags: errors, subfloats

```
\documentclass[journal]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage[classicReIm]{kpfonts}
\usepackage{booktabs,tabularx,lipsum
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[H]
    \centering

    \subfigure [\ RBM-based load forecast] {\includegraphics[width=7.5cm, keepaspectratio]{F_Load.eps} \label{fig1:subfig1}}
    \subfigure [\ RBM-based RTPS forecast] {\includegraphics[width=7.5cm, keepaspectratio]{F_RTPS.eps} \label{fig1:subfig2}} %\vspace{-6pt}
    \subfigure [\ RBM-based CPPS forecast] {\includegraphics[width=7.5cm, keepaspectratio]{F_CPPS.eps} \label{fig1:subfig2}} %\vspace{-6pt}

    \caption[]{Price incentive-based DR schemes.}

    \label{fig1}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: One thing is that `\usepackage{booktabs,tabularx,lipsum` misses a closing `}`. If you use `\usepackage{booktabs,tabularx,lipsum,float,subfigure,graphicx}` probably the errors will go away but `subfigure` is said to deprecated.

Comment: Well, which error do you get? Please make sure that your given code results in the error you get! At the moment that it is impossible, because you missed a closing `}` and some package calls ... Why did you tag with `sidewaysfigure`?

Answer (score 1):

Several packages are missing:

- `float` to use `[H]`
- `graphicx` to include images
- `subfigure` for the `\subfigure` macro

multiple use of same label is also bad and missing `}` in preamble

```
\documentclass[journal]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage[classicReIm]{kpfonts}
\usepackage{booktabs,tabularx,lipsum}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subfigure}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[H]
    \centering
    \subfigure[RBM-based load forecast]{\includegraphics[width=7.5cm, keepaspectratio]{example-image}\label{fig1:subfig1}}
    \subfigure[RBM-based RTPS forecast] {\includegraphics[width=7.5cm, keepaspectratio]{example-image} \label{fig1:subfig2}} %\vspace{-6pt}
    \subfigure[RBM-based CPPS forecast] {\includegraphics[width=7.5cm, keepaspectratio]{example-image} \label{fig1:subfig3}} %\vspace{-6pt}
    \caption[]{Price incentive-based DR schemes.}
    \label{fig1}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In your given code there are several issues:

1. You have a missing `}` in your line `\usepackage{booktabs,tabularx,lipsum` .
2. Related to your issue with a figure you need not to call `booktabs` and `tabularx`.
3. You need to load package `float` to be able to use `[H]`. We need to load package `graphicx` with package option `draft` to be able to use your used filenames for the used images.
4. A blank line inside `figure` results in starting a new paragraph. You have too much blank lines in your `figure` environment, delete all of them. To get the three subfigures above each other you need a blank line between subfigures one and two and a blank line between subfigures two and three.
5. Instead the outdated package `subfigure` use `subcaption` or `subfig`. Please see that both call package `caption` which results in an warning. To avoid this simply do not use a package for subfigures, use only figures. For the following example I used `subfig`.
6. Use better labels for you figure (and tables and ...). Better is `\label{fig:<name>}`, so you can better remember and can use the same name for a table, a chapter, etc. if you use a leading `fig:` or `tab:` or `cha:` or ...
7. To be able to check if your used figure fits the column I used package `showframe` to visualize the typing area and margins only for this mwe.

Please have a look to this code:

```
\documentclass[journal]{IEEEtran}

\usepackage[classicReIm]{kpfonts}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{subfig} % <=================================================
\usepackage[draft]{graphicx} % <========================================
\usepackage{float} % <==================================================
\usepackage{showframe}


\begin{document}

\begin{figure}%[H]
  \centering
  \subfloat[RBM-based load forecast\label{fig:subfig1}]{\includegraphics[width=7.2cm, keepaspectratio]{F_Load.eps}}

  \subfloat[RBM-based RTPS forecast\label{fig:subfig2}]{\includegraphics[width=7.2cm, keepaspectratio]{F_RTPS.eps}}

  \subfloat[RBM-based CPPS forecast\label{fig:subfig3}]{\includegraphics[width=7.2cm, keepaspectratio]{F_CPPS.eps}}
  \caption{Price incentive-based DR schemes.}
  \label{fig:figure1}
\end{figure}
\lipsum

Text see subfigures~\ref{fig:subfig1} and~\ref{fig:subfig3}.
\end{document}
```

and its result:

[image: resulting page]

Please note that I had to correct your used width for the images from `7.5cm` to `width=7.2cm` to get all three subfigures fitting one complete column ...

I guess the error message you got was `floating too large ...`

Answer (score 1):

You're missing the appropriate package for subfloats.

You cannot use `subcaption`, because `caption` is incompatible with `IEEEtran`. The `subfigure` package is obsolete. The only choice is therefore `subfig`, with the `caption=false` option so the incompatible `caption` will not be loaded.

Instead of explicit width of 7.5cm I used `0.9\columnwidth`; note that `keepaspectratio` is not needed. It might make sense to use `\columnwidth`.

I also added a trick for making the float to fill the column, but it depends on the final height of the images.

```latex
\documentclass[journal]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage[classicReIm]{kpfonts}
\usepackage{booktabs,tabularx,graphicx}

\usepackage[caption=false]{subfig}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1-3]

\begin{figure}
\centering

\subfloat[RBM-based load forecast]{%
  \includegraphics[width=0.9\columnwidth]{example-image}\label{fig1:subfig1}%
}

\subfloat[RBM-based RTPS forecast]{%
  \includegraphics[width=0.9\columnwidth]{example-image}\label{fig1:subfig2}%
}

\subfloat[RBM-based CPPS forecast]{%
  \includegraphics[width=0.9\columnwidth]{example-image}\label{fig1:subfig3}%
}

\caption{Price incentive-based DR schemes.}\label{fig1}
\end{figure}

\lipsum[4-5]

\begin{figure}

\sbox0{\small Fg}

\begin{minipage}[t][\dimexpr\textheight-\ht0][s]{\columnwidth}
\centering

\subfloat[RBM-based load forecast]{%
  \includegraphics[width=0.9\columnwidth]{example-image}\label{fig1:subfig1-m}%
}

\vfill

\subfloat[RBM-based RTPS forecast]{%
  \includegraphics[width=0.9\columnwidth]{example-image}\label{fig1:subfig2-m}%
}

\vfill

\subfloat[RBM-based CPPS forecast]{%
  \includegraphics[width=0.9\columnwidth]{example-image}\label{fig1:subfig3-m}%
}

\caption{Price incentive-based DR schemes.}\label{fig1-m}

\vspace{-\dp0}

\end{minipage}
\end{figure}

\lipsum

\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]